# Storing same object in different arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object, reference

For the following code:

```
User myUser = new User();
User[] array1 = new User[10];
User[] array2 = new User[10];
array1[5] = myUser;
array2[5] = myUser;
```

Is the object myUser stored twice, or is only the address of the object stored on each of the objects?

Also does this still hold if i start messing around with the variable like:

```
temp = myUser;
array2[4] = temp;
```

Also if i make a change to myUser in one array, does it make the change to the other array?

EDIT: last question how would one store it by value instead of reference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicating objects in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072727/duplicating-objects-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, only the reference to the `User` object is stored in the array. Each of the reference points to the same object. Modifying the object through either of the arrays will modify the same one object.

The same applies to storing the refernce in variables as in your second example.

Only [primitive types](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/java/miscellaneous_java/Java_Primitive_Types.html) are stored by value, e.g. `int`, `boolean`, `char`. Note that they also have corresponding reference type, e.g. for `int` you have `Integer`.

Comment: Great so it only stored once. Last question how would one avoid this so that this dosen't happen. I.e. its stored by value instead

Comment: The only things stored by value (in arrays and collections) are primitives: ints, booleans, chars, etc.

Comment: You need to create a deep copy of the object to avoid it.

Comment: @YahyaUddin You would have to manually create a deep copy of the object; specifics depend on the exact nature of the data in your object. Typical techniques include defining a constructor that takes another instance of your object and copies its values, and/or overriding `Object.clone()`.

Comment: "Only primitive types are stored by value, e.g. int, boolean, char." Huh. I couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: @user2310289 No, not at all. You'd have to override `clone()` as a public method first, and decide which members deserved deep vs. shallow copies. You really should consider deleting that comment as without further explanation it's incredibly misleading advice.

Comment: @JasonC I think your comment has enhanced my comment to that degree.

Comment: @user2310289 Huh. I guess it did, didn't it?

Comment: You can also use Object.assign() for semi deep copy, it isn't a completely deep copy because it won't create a new copy for reference types in the object. You can also use Object.create(). However Object.create puts it in the prototype

Comment: Yeah this screwed up a code I had, and I was wondering what happened.