# Two java variables referencing same string object don't sync

Tags: java

From my novice perspective of Java object, if two variables referencing one object, updating one variable should do the same to the other, as the code shows below:

```
SomeObject s1 = new SomeObject("first");
SomeObject s2 = s1;
s2.setText("second");
System.out.println(s1.getText()); // print second
System.out.println(s2.getText()); // print second as well
```

I referenced the code from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072727/duplicating-objects-in-java).

However, this doesn't apply to String class. See code below:

```
String s_1 = new String("first");
String s_2 = s_1;
s_2 = "second";
System.out.println("s_1: " + s_1 + " s_2:  " + s_2); 
//s_1 appears to be "first" and s_2 "second"
```

Is this because the difference between String class and self-declared class? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the difference is in the kind of change you make.

This code:

```
s2.setText("second")
```

doesn't change the value of either `s2` or `s1`. Both `s1` and `s2` refer to the same object as they did before... but the contents of the object has changed.

Compare that with this code:

```
s_2 = "second";
```

Here you're changing the value of `s2` to be a reference to a different object. Changing the value of `s_2` doesn't change the value of `s_1` at all - it still refers to the same object that it did before.

You probably want to read up on [the differences between variables, objects and references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172) - once you can get that clear in your head, everything else will make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

A `String` object can be initialized without the constructor being called. So when you initialize `s_2` to `s_1`, it is given the value of it and when you initialize `s_2 = "second"` it is overwritten. It is same as `s2 = s1` and then `s2 = new SomeObject ("second")`