# Need help understanding the output of this code

Tags: java

I'm a beginner so it really doesn't get any simpler than this.
I got 2 separate .java files in a folder.
A class responsible for the "attributes" of a dog (name, age, breed etc).

```
   ...
   public String name;
   public byte age;
   public String breed;

      public String makeNoise()
      {
         return "Woof...";
      }

      public String toString()
      {
         return "Name: " +name +"\n" +"Age: " +age +"\n" +"Breed: " +breed;
      }
      ...
```

And a Tester to test the dog class.

```
  ...  
  Dog d1 = new Dog();
  d1.name = "Frodo";
  d1.age = 4;
  d1.breed = "Alsatian";

  Dog d2 = new Dog();
  d2.name = "Labby";
  d2.age = 3;
  d2.breed = "Labrador";

  Dog d3 = d2;
  d3.age = 6;
  d3.name = "Mike";


 System.out.println(d1.name);
 System.out.println(d2.age);
 System.out.println(d3.age);
 System.out.println(d2.name);

 System.out.println(d1.age == d2.age);
 System.out.println(d1 == d2);
 System.out.println(d1 == d3);
 System.out.println(d2 == d3);
 ...
```

The output of

```
System.out.println(d2.age);
```

Is returning 6, for some reason, and I don't understand why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: as a side note, never ever compare objects, as `d1 == d2` with the `=` operator, unless you want to check if they refer to the same instance. override [Object#equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) and make use of the `equals` functions to determine logical equality.

Comment: Refer to this question for more details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072727/duplicating-objects-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you make the assignment

```
Dog d3 = d2;
```

You are copying a reference of a `Dog` object from the `d2` variable to the `d3` variable. You are not making a copy of the object.

Therefore, after the assignment, both `d3` and `d2` refer to the same `Dog` object. Therefore `d3.age = 6;` causes `d2.age` to be `6`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, every variable (except primitives) is actually pointer. So what you are really doing here is next:

1. `Dog d1 = new Dog();`
   This makes new instance of dog and d1 points to it.
2. `Dog d2 = new Dog();`
   This makes another instance of dog and d2 points to it.
3. `Dog d3 = d2;`
   Here you say that `d3` is pointer to an instance of dog and in same line you say that instance is same as instance that `d2` points to.
4. `d3.age = 6; d3.name = "Mike";`
   This two lines are making changes on `Dog` instance that `d3` (and `d2`) is pointing to.

If you wanted to make a copy of instance (create new instance with same values of attributes) you should write copy constructor or implement `Cloneable` interface and use `clone()` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dog d3 = d2;
d3.age = 6;
```

Here you have set the age of `d2` to 6, because you have `d2` and `d3` both referring to the same object. This is how the assignment operator `=` works in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Since

```
Dog d3 = d2
```

`d2` and `d3` are referencing to the same object. As you change `d3.age`, it will also change `d2.age`.

Not only `age`, but also `name` and `breed` will be changed for both `d2` and `d3`. If you check `d2.name`, you will get "Mike", not "Labby".

Answer (score 1):

```
Dog d3 = d2;
```

This means that d2 and d3 are the same object / point to the same instance.

```
d3.age = 6;
```

This means that d2.age is 6