# java string reverse algorithm

Tags: java, string, algorithm, reverse

I am trying to write my own string reverse algorithm (I know this already exists in java but I am doing this for education). The code below is what I have so far. It outputs only half the string reversed. I have done some debugging and the reason is that it is changing *stringChars2* at the same time as *stringChars* but I have no idea why that is happening as I am only trying to change *stringChars*. All help greatly appreciated.

*EDIT* my question was not "how to reverse a string" which has been asked before... but why my objects where changing without instruction, the answer below completely explains the problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //declare variables
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String myString = "";
    int length = 0, index = 0, index2 = 0;

    //get input string
    System.out.print("Enter the string you want to reverse: ");
    myString = input.next();

    //find length of string
    length = myString.length()-1;
    index2 = length;

    //convert to array
    char[] stringChars = myString.toCharArray();
    char[] stringChars2 = stringChars;

    //loop through and reverse order
    while (index<length) {

        stringChars[index] = stringChars2[index2];

        index++;
        index2--;
    }

    //convert back to string
    String newString = new String(stringChars);

    //output result
    System.out.println(newString);

    //close resources
    input.close();

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Comment: What do you think the following statement does: `char[] stringChars2 = stringChars;`?

Comment: [Make copy of array Java](//stackoverflow.com/q/5785745)

Comment: I'm just a beginner... objects are not my thing yet ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char[] stringChars = myString.toCharArray();
char[] stringChars2 = stringChars;
```

On the second line you are assigning `stringChars2` to the same object as `stringChars` so basically they are one and the same and when you change the first you are changing the second as well.

**Try something like this instead:**

```
char[] stringChars = myString.toCharArray();
char[] stringChars2 = myString.toCharArray();
```

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072727/duplicating-objects-in-java)

Comment: Thanks man, I realise now this is a silly mistake but you really helped me out.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If the answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

All that is not necessary.
You can simply reverse a string with a for loop (in a method):

```
public String reverseString(String str)
{
    String output = "";
    int len = str.length();
    for(int k = 1; k <= str.length(); k++, len--)
    {
        output += str.substring(len-1,len);
    }
    return output;
}
```